# user defined sorting in pageblocktable

Tags: apex, visualforce, table

I have a **picklist** field "**target**", the values are "**primary**","**secondary**","**tertiary**" and "**optional**". We have only one "**primary**","**secondary**" and "**tertiary**" records but many "**optional**" records.

The table should display "**primary**" record as first then "**secondary**" then "**tertiary**" then "**optional**" records. We are able to delete the record also.

How can we sort the records? Is there any way to do this using jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Are you using a custom controller or controller extension with this page? This would be simpler to do within Apex before it gets to the page.

Comment: I am using custom controller. List<custom_object__c> listTemp = Database.query('SELECT id, name,target__c FROM custom_object__c. This is the list in get method and we r populating this list n page.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ORDER BY keyword in SOQL query or override javascript sort function

Comment: `ORDER BY` in SOQL would go in alphabetical order of the picklist values, which is not OP's desired order. This would only work if the picklist values themselves were in order. I.e. "1 - Primary", "2 - Secondary", "3 - Tertiary", "9 - Optional"